# mootools fx.reveal

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-fx

I'm trying to do a simple show/hide transition for a message div using fx.reveal in mootools 1.4. The effect works the first time, but not on subsequent clicks.

Any hints as to where I'm going wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/MYgH6/1/

```
var mytween = new Fx.Reveal(document.getElementById('mydiv'), {duration: 2500});

$('myclick').addEvent('click', function(){
    mymessage();
});

function mymessage(){
    var mymessage = document.getElementById('mydiv');

    mymessage.set('html','YO!');

    mytween.reveal();
    mytween.dissolve();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var mytween = new Fx.Reveal(document.getElementById('mydiv'), {
    duration: 1000,
    onComplete:function(){
        this.element.dissolve();
    }
});

$('myclick').addEvent('click', function(){
    mymessage();
});

function mymessage(){
    var mymessage = document.getElementById('mydiv');

    mymessage.set('html','YO!');

    mytween.reveal();
}
```

Comment: so toggle twice? since toggle sets to show if hidden, and hidden if shown-- I don't think that toggle does the show-then-hide that I'm looking for. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not best answer, as you specified using Fx.Reveal, but I'd use wink command 
http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Reveal#Element:wink

Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/MYgH6/5/

```
var msg = document.getElementById('mydiv').hide();
$('myclick').addEvent('click', function() {
    msg.wink();
});
```

You can certainly specify the message within the function as you did before.